# jquery change the name and href at the link

Tags: jquery, html

i have an link with this href

```html
<div id="site_change">
<a id="mysite" href="https://halloweentorino.com/">halloween torino</a>
</div>
```

but i want change href and the name of link with in

```html
<div id="site_change">
<a id="mysite" href="http://amadreams.it/">amadreams torino</a>
</div>
```

i write this code in jquery

```js
$("#mysites").attr("href", "http://amadreams.it/");
$('#mysites').attr('title','amadreams torino');
```

but doesn't working!

Comment: the id's don't match. Try `$("#mysite")` instead of `$("#mysites")`

Comment: Why are you attempting to change the title if you want to change the link's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id is `mysite` and you are trying to change the attribute using `mysites` which is wrong. So change it to:

```
$("#mysite").attr("href", "http://amadreams.it/");
$('#mysite').attr('title','amadreams torino');
```

and try again. And one more thing, there is no `title` passed initially.